# Identify keyboard localization

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

What keyboard localization is present on this MacBook?

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question to change layout to localization. If that's not what you are seeking, please feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Sir u know better then me... but can u please tell me which layout is this? Because the french one has azerty keyboard and some keys are change..

Comment: There's a difference between keyboard layout and localization. The one which I posted in the answer (referenced from the Apple support document) is the only one which matches with localization of your MacBook's keyboard. However the sample illustration shows `AZERTY` layout instead of `QWERTY`. Can you update the question to specify the model of your MacBook Pro?

Comment: Sir its a macbook pro early 2015 13inch

Comment: It looks like some kind of hybrid; it's a French layout but with what looks like a standard UK or International English qwerty inset. The letters match qwerty, including where the azerty layout has to 'move' keys elsewhere.

Comment: I do not speak French. Referring to the [Apple support document](https://support.apple.com/HT201794), the localization very closely matches with French keyboard. However, I am unsure if French locale keyboards are available in QWERTY layout as all my searches have only returned AZERTY keyboards. I'll update my answer to include discussion from the comments.

Comment: How to use this layout correctly? Cuz when i type “?” It shows “/“ this.. ?

Comment: You need to work through the list of Apple keyboard layouts and match your keyboard. Once you have done that then you need to go into system preferences and load the correct keyboard layout there. One hint - make sure your password is simple at this point as some characters may not be available on boot (been there had it happen). The answer gives the link to the apple keyboards.

Comment: Can anybody please help me? Cuz i dont know how to do that.

Comment: I have tried it and nothing matches my keyboard except “FRENCH” but it have “AZERTY” keyboard and some keys on french keyboard are also different..

Comment: @YousafAshraf I asked around a couple French native guys (one of them is a long time employee of Apple working from HQ). They are certain that the keys have been manually swapped. Possibly that explains why you are getting incorrect inputs.

Comment: Nimesh brother what should i do now? Can i put them back in their place is their a way to do that?

Comment: I couldn't give any advise on manually swapping out keys. Best way would be to get in touch with the person who handed you the MacBook as he/she must have swapped the keys in the first place. If you choose to swap back keys, you can follow the illustration I linked in the answer. That's all I can say.

Comment: @YousafAshraf No issues. I'll update the answer to reflect discussion from comments.

Comment: Ok  stay blessed brother.

Comment: Your only resort if you want the keyboard to input correctly is to pick out keys and put them back as shown in the diagram in Apple Support document (linked in the answer).

Comment: If you want this keyboard as is to input correctly, you will need to create a custom layout using Ukelele or Karabiner.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It very closely resembles **French** keyboard localization</strike> as per Apple support document, [How to identify keyboard localizations](https://support.apple.com/HT201794).

The keyboard has French localization. The keys have been manually swapped to change the layout.

[image]

However, the layout on your keyboard is **QWERTY** while Apple support document illustrates **AZERTY** layout.

As mentioned by [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332601/identify-keyboard-localization#comment427410_332601):

> It looks like some kind of hybrid; it's a French layout but with what looks like a standard UK or International English qwerty inset. The letters match qwerty, including where the azerty layout has to 'move' keys elsewhere

In order to have output match the keys, you could create a custom layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) or [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Comment: But sir my keyboard layout is still different some keys are different?

Comment: @Tetsujin can you edit the answer to add your thoughts?

Comment: No prob - I see you added it. btw, @tags don't work if that person was not already part of the specific comment thread.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the info. I shared a link to this question with a couple natives from France. Got them puzzled too. It appears French locale keyboards doesn't come with QWERTY layout.

Comment: Well, French is spoken across a significant area of Africa - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_entities_where_French_is_an_official_language - maybe from one of those??

Comment: @Tetsujin See my last comment on the question.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Canadian French keyboards are Qwerty.  But they are different than this one.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the info. As it turns out, the keys on this one has been manually shuffled.