# MacBook Pro: Keyboard layout mismatch

Tags: mac, keyboard, high-sierra

I just received my repackaged MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 inches, end 2012) and I have a problem with my keyboard. The keyboard layout is different from the one I had before, and I can't find the right one in the input types of the system!

So what's problematic: I have the `@#` key above the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, but when I press it, I get `<>`. Then, I have the `<>` key below the delete key (which is weird I've never seen that layout before) and when I press it, I get `£`.

Otherwise the keys seem to work fine.

I have an AZERTY keyboard and I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65). The language associated with it isn't really important as long as when I press a key, it actually gives me the character printed on it!

So my question is: Is there anyway to fix that? Somewhere to download another keyboard layout? Does apple have some hidden layout somewhere? Do I have to write my own layout and if so how?

I've looked at all the languages available in the system right now and searched for hours on Google but I didn't find anything.

**EDIT**
I usually type in french. Here's a photo of my keyboard :

[image: Keyboard photo]

Comment: Please post a photo of this thing.  Also what is the language you type in normally?

Comment: @TomGewecke I added a photo to my post.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing. It is indeed an ANSI keyboard and not ISO. Apple has never made an azerty ANSI keyboard as far as I know, and no ANSI software layout has @# on the same top level key.

Comment: Okay... So all I can do is make my own keyboard ?

Comment: Yes, I would use Ukelele and start with the French layout in ANSI type.  I think only a few keys need to be modified.

Comment: Here is one that may work:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/84vlsspzzi5yomg/French%20Mod.keylayout?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Belgian and French Apple layouts are AZERTY.  If you have either the French or Belgian input source active, they will give you @# above Tab.  But <> will be next to the left shift before W.  Your picture indicates this latter key is missing, so it is not a proper French/Belgian keyboard, but some kind of mishmash, with keys from an ISO keyboard grafted onto an ANSI keyboard.

The only keyboard with <> near Delete is Turkish, which is different everywhere else, and also has the extra key,

To get output to match your keys you will need a custom layout made with Ukelele or Karabiner.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/84vlsspzzi5yomg/French%20Mod.keylayout?dl=0) is one I made with Ukelele which may work.  You put the French Mod.keylayout file in Library/Keyboard Layouts and then go to system preferences/keyboard/input sources and use the plus and add buttons to activate (it will be in the Others category).

Comment: @Kazuya, Tom: There was a similar query with an unidentified keyboard layout  a few days ago on Ask Different. Go through the comments in the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332601/identify-keyboard-localization/332602#332602).

Comment: @NimeshNeema I didn't find a turkish keyboard with my layout.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the offending keys were manually swapped. You can manually pluck them out and re-swap them in place.

Refer to this Apple support document, [How to identify keyboard localizations](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201794) and identify the correct keyboard.

> Is there anyway to fix that?

Yes, you'll need to re-swap the keys to their correct location.

> Somewhere to download another keyboard layout?

No.

> Does apple have some hidden layout somewhere?

No.

> Do I have to write my own layout and if so how?

Nada.

There are various guides on Web on how to pluck out and swap keys on a 2012 retina MacBook Pro.

Comment: If his keyboard is ANSI and not ISO swapping keys may not be possible and writing his own layout with Ukelele or Karabiner will be the only fix.

Comment: I doubt the keys have been swapped because what they type isn't what's displayed on the other key.

Comment: @Kazuya Right. The keys with <> and @# on them would have to have come from another ISO type keyboard. No Apple input source for ANSI will fit this. So you have to make one for yourself. I'm really curious how this keyboard could have gotten put together....