# Karabiner elements: key not appearing in "Simple modification" list

Tags: karabiner

**TL,DR: How do I swap "<" and "²" on an AZERTY keyboard ?**

**Context**
I'm running macOS Ventura 13.0.1. I have an MS Natural Keyboard 4000 with an AZERTY layout. The physical key at the right of the left-most <kbd>Shift</kbd> has a "<" and a ">" sign printed on it. The physical key at the top of the left <kbd>Tab</kbd> key has a "²" printed on it. For some reason, pressing the key with a "<" displays a "²", and vice-versa. I would like to swap the keys.

**Attempts**
Apparently, there is no built-in way to do that in macOS Ventura 13.0.1, so I installed [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) which advertises as an application to do just that.

I was hoping that following the [Configure Simple Notification](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/configure-simple-modifications/) documentation would help; unfortunately, I cannot find any keys in the **Add item** list that matches the "<" key. (I was hoping for any "lower_than", "less_than", "left_xxxx" key but cannot find them in the list.)

I then switched to [Configure Complex Modifications](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/configure-complex-modifications/), which opens a browser to lookup a rule; however, none of the rules seem to match (and it does not seem like searching for "<" is supposed to help.)

**Next steps ?**
Am I just missing the name of the "<" key in plain sight? Do I need to configure Karabiner to expose keys for AZERTY keyboards? Is it a specific issue with this keyboard? Should I manually edit the `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`, and in which case, which section should I change, to which value?

Comment: Character Viewer calls it `LESS-THAN SIGN` Unicode U+003C. I can't help with Karabiner, but this might be an easy job for [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/)

Comment: Do you have instructions on how to do it with Ukelele ? So far i have not be able to do it (I can create a custom layout that should in theory swap the keys, and install it, but the keys are still not swapped.)

Comment: What does Karabinier-EventViewer show when the keys are pressed?

Comment: `non_us_backslash`, which is _not_ the key I want to rebind. (I have another key on my keyboard with a backslash on it, and I'm not using a US keyboard.) But for some reason, it works.

Comment: @phtrivier If Karabinier thinks it is non_us_backslash then it IS the key you want to rebind. I suspect the MS keyboard does not exactly match what macOS thinks is an AZERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue : I use an external azerty keyboard with French-PC layout + karabiner to switch left option and command keys but when I was using built-in macbook keyboard with French layout, "<" key printed "²".

This [issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333368/macbook-pro-keyboard-layout-mismatch) put me on track :

- when karabiner was running, keyboard viewer was displaying [ANSI layout](https://hfr-meca.github.io/guide/04-layout.html)
- when karabiner wasn't running, ISO layout was displayed.

Setting *Virtual keyboard* to ISO in karabiner fixed my issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the top-left ` being mapped to the `§` key (right next to the left-shift key). I solved it by switching my Karabiner's *Virtual keyboard* from `ISO` to `ANSI`. Thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the key that has a "<" sign on it, is, *obviously*, "non_us_backslash".

R.I.P Fred Brooks.